# VBA Regex - How to match anything except a specific string?

Tags: regex, vba

Sorry if the answer was out there somewhere.  I did my research but couldn't find it.

I want to build a regular expression pattern that will match a line in the following format:

1. Begins with the word "sccp"
2. Followed by a space
3. Followed by anything except "ccm group"

I know that ^ in square brackets means "except for any of the characters".  How do I exclude a phrase instead of single characters?  Obviously, the pattern below didn't do what I wanted:

```
^sccp [^ccm group]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `^sccp (?!ccm group)` or `^sccp (?!ccm group).*` which uses a negative lookahead to assert that the phrase "ccm group" does not come after the space. [Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/TBO4K1/2).

If "sccp " should not match (i.e. nothing after the space), then use `^sccp (?!ccm group).+`.

Information on the negative lookahead can be found [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).